# access vba execute after inserting new record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a vba for generating a random number. This number is generated after opening the form, this is good, but it also needs to generate a code after a new record is made, how can this be done?

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strPin As String
Dim i As Integer

strPin = "JobNr: "

'Set seed
Call Randomize

For i = 1 To 5
   strPin = strPin & Int(10 * Rnd)
Next

Me.random_nr = strPin
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that code is doing what you want, you can move it to a separate procedure in the form's module.

```
Private Sub UpdateRandNum()
    Dim strPin As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strPin = "JobNr: "

    'Set seed '
    Call Randomize

    For i = 1 To 5
       strPin = strPin & Int(10 * Rnd)
    Next

    Me.random_nr = strPin
End Sub
```

Then change Form Open:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    UpdateRandNum
End Sub
```

And call it again from the form's After Insert event.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    UpdateRandNum
End Sub
```